# libraryでパッケージが使えない

Tags: r

素人でお恥ずかしい質問で申し訳ございません。
Rのsemをインストールできているはずなのに、library(sem)で以下のようなエラーが表示されてしまいます。

・・という名前のパッケージはありません
エラー：semに対するパッケージもしくは名前空間のロードが失敗しました

という表示が出るので、・・に相当するパッケージをインストールしてみました。そしてlibrary(sem)を行うと今度は

＊＊という名前のパッケージはありません
エラー：semに対するパッケージもしくは名前空間のロードが失敗しました

という表示が出て来きてしまい、**をインストールしても今度は別の名前のパッケージがありません、という表示が出てくる、という状態を繰り返しています。
解決策を教えて頂ければと存じます。library()でsemはインストールされたパッケージのリストに入っているので、インストールはできているのではないかと考えていますが、どういうわけかlibaryで読み込めないようです。

Answer (score 1):

依存されているパッケージも併せてインストールすることをおすすめします。
`install.packages("sem", dependencies=TRUE)`で、semが必要としているパッケージをインストールすることができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご指摘頂いた通りに依存されているパッケージもインストールしたのですが、それでもうまく行きませんでした。以下のような表示が出て来てしまいます。

install.packages("sem", dependencies=TRUE)
URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/sem_3.1-9.tgz' を試しています

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 608687 bytes (594 KB)
downloaded 594 KB

ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります 
/var/folders/pp/38t_h1_j74bfyjzdwwjm755h0000gn/T//RtmppliB4k/downloaded_packages

library("sem")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
‘nloptr’ という名前のパッケージはありません 
エラー: ‘sem’ に対するパッケージもしくは名前空間のロードが失敗しました

Comment: 回答ではないのですが、私も同じエラーが出て関数の呼び出しに失敗しているのですが、解決されましたか？

Comment: `install.packages("sem", dependencies=TRUE)`で、`‘nloptr’ という名前のパッケージはありません`といったエラーが出た場合、参照されているパッケージ(ここではnloptr)もinstall.packagesでインストールする必要があります。